# Is it possible to create a test that shows the failure of double-checked locking in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

So here is my custom utility for double-checked locking: it's a static method into which you feed the criterion, the synchronisation object and the action to be performed.

```
public static bool RunIf(Func<bool> criterion, object syncObject, Action action)
{
    if (criterion())
        lock(syncObject)
            if (criterion())
            {
                Thread.MemoryBarrier(); 
                action();
                return true;
            }
    return false;
}
```

I am given to understand that, according to the C# specification, it is possible for optimisers to reorder memory allocations in such a way that, without the memory barrier, this technique can give a false positive and execute the action when it shouldn't.

In my little world, if such a failure is possible, it should also be possible to devise a test that demonstrates the failure consistently by hitting the scenario hard enough with a sufficient number of parallel test cases.  I have been searching for such a test for around a year now, but so far I've drawn a blank.  Can anyone show me a test that:

1. shows the failure of this method in the absence of the memory barrier;
2. shows its success when the test is repeated with the memory barrier restored?

Comment: I believe .Net framework on x86 has stronger memory model than what the C# specification requires, so you won't be able to create such test. You might have more luck on ARM (i.e. Windows RT), which has weaker memory model.

Comment: svick is correct. Check out [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx#S5) which talks about the stronger memory model for .Net 2+.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to test non-deterministic behavior (or at least, if you do then a negative result is still inconclusive).

Comment: Agree, one could come up with a test to get two threads to call the method.  However, you cannot deterministically switch between the two threads.  The pattern implemented however, is well known and a simple code review should be done.

Comment: This raises another question.  You could actually ditch the double-checked locking entirely, and implement a simple-minded unsafe singleton pattern.  Although there is no guarantee that this will fail when hit by parallel threads -- this is, as you say, non-deterministic behaviour -- if you hit it with a few million parallel threads, the chances that it will fail are so great that it is effectively a deterministic test.  Would that be bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to construct such a test, because the "lock" statement already creates a full fence (i.e. an acquire and release fence) for the locked block of instructions. Thus the additional `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` is superfluous and has no effect.

So, depending on what the passed in delegate `criterion` does, your `RunIf` construct is either safe or completely superfluous itself.

What I mean by this, is that if the passed in `criterion` delegate derives its return value from mutable state, and this mutable state is not protected (either directly or indirectly) by the same `syncObject`, this code is not safe and `RunIf` basically has no effect at all except for surrounding the instructions performed in the second call to the `criterion` delegate with a full fence.